# Subsetting specific values of a variable, based on a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subsetting my dataset using one variable ("id"), selecting specific values based on a vector ("x"). For example, considering these data and vector x:

```
id <- c(31,32,33,34,35)
z<- c(1,1,2,3,4)
y <- c(8,4,12,6,15)
data <- data.frame(id,z,y)

x <- (31,34)
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
id <- c(31,34)
z <- c(1,3)
y <- c(8,6)
data <- data.frame(id,z,y)
```

Comment: Try `subset(data, id %in% x)` where `x <- c(31,34)`

Comment: `data[data['id']==x,]`?

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick! Your suggestion solved my question!